# Will Await Call in Child componentDidMount Block Parent Rendering?

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I am wondering if I got some components like this

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};
      }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({value:await ajaxCallToServer() }) 
      }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Child {this.state.value}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

will Child basically block Parent from rendering till Child is done with it's ajax request?

Comment: No, child component will not block parent component from rendering. Child component state will be updated asynchronously and it will be re-rendered but  parent component is rendered only once.

Comment: Your question is phrased for a 'Yes/No' type of answers which are more for comments. Not sure if you meant to inquire on how to block parent component till child is rendered.

Comment: yeah guess it is factored as yes/no. If it was a yes then my question would be how to get around it. I have some pages where it seems like stuff is sluggish and was wondering if it was being blocked by the ajax calls or not. Since it is not, it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

No, child component will not block parent component from rendering.

At first, both `Parent` and `Child` component is rendered but `Child` component is rendered with state `value: ""`.

And when the ajax/ network request is completed successfully, `Child` component state is updated and `Child` component is re-rendered with updated state.

You can update the `Child` component with below code and see the result.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
  }

  fakePromise = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve("Foo"), 10000);
    });
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ value: await this.fakePromise() });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Child {this.state.value}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```